# Creating a form in Access to get the Customer Information

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have created a database named `Customer_master` in which I have some customer information saved in an MS Access database.

I am trying to create a Form so that I can enter a Mobile Number and click the <kbd>Search</kbd> button and get the Customer Name.

The form is created with the Mobile Number & Customer Name as text boxes and a Search button in front of the mobile number.

As I am new to VBA, I think there is some coding issue.

Below is the code I have tried for the Search button:

```vb
Private Sub Command6_Click()
    Dim strsearch As String
    Dim Task As String

    'Check if a keyword entered or not
    If IsNull(Me.Mobile_Number) Or Me.Mobile_Number = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please type in your search keyword.", vbOKOnly, "Keyword Needed"
    Else
        strsearch = Me.Mobile_Number.Value
        Task = "SELECT Customer_Name FROM Customer_Master WHERE ((Mobile_Number Like ""*" & strsearch & "*""))"

        Me.RecordSource = Task
    End If
End Sub
```

After I enter the Mobile Number and click on the Search button nothing is happening as I am not getting the name of the customer.

Comment: Code looks ok. Please read and apply: [How to debug VBA code](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx) and [How to debug dynamic SQL in VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/418960/managing-and-debugging-sql-queries-in-ms-access/1099570#1099570)

Comment: You need to `Requery` after assigning: `Me.Form.RecordSource = Task: Me.Form.Requery`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative way to achieve this is to create a new query in access against the datasource, and in the query definition pass the value from your search form to the query, using FORMS!VALUE.

You can then add a button to your form and save the VBA code to execute the query on click. by adding in the line DoCmd.OpenQuery